Cannot Access Collection in Simulation Agent from Learner Agent in AnyLogic
I am working on an agent-based simulation in AnyLogic where I need to adjust certain factors for each learner agent based on slider inputs. The top-level agent in my model is Main. I have a collection in my Simulation Agent called 'factorAdjustments'. This collection stores adjustments made through 15 sliders, as seen in the attached screenshot.

The goal is to apply these adjustments to the Learner agents as they enter at the entry point (as can be seen in the screenshot of my Learner Agent). Only after these adjustments have been made, I want the simulation to run. 
The entry action of this state is applyAdjustments(factorAdjustments); and this is where the error is coming from:
Description: factorAdjustments cannot be resolved to a variable. 
Location: Learner_progression/Learner/enter - State

Here's the code I'm using to apply the adjustments:
// Access the Main agent instance
Main main = (Main) get_Main();

// Ensure the learners population is not empty before accessing the first learner
if (!main.learners.isEmpty()) {
    // Iterate over the factor adjustments
    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : factorAdjustments.entrySet()) {
        String factorName = entry.getKey();
        double percentageChange = entry.getValue();

        // Retrieve the first Learner in the population
        Learner sampleLearner = main.learners.get(0);
        double minFactor = sampleLearner.min_fscore(factorName);
        double maxFactor = sampleLearner.max_fscore(factorName);

        // Iterate over all learners and apply changes
        for (Learner learner : main.learners) {
            learner.change_fscore(factorName, minFactor, maxFactor, percentageChange);
        }
    }
}

I have defined the factorAdjustments collection in the Simulation agent, which should collect the slider adjustments. However, I am not sure how to properly access this collection from within the Learner agent.
The objective is to adjust the sliders, let these changes affect the variables of the Learner agents, and then run the simulation.
Could someone help me understand how to properly access the factorAdjustments collection in the Simulation agent from the Learner agent?
Additional Context:

The Simulation agent has the sliders and the factorAdjustments collection.
The Main agent holds the learners population.
Attached is a screenshot of the simulation interface for reference.

Thank you for your help!
P.s. I tried all kinds of references to the Simulation Agent but I am obviously not understanding the construct of the three agents (Main, Simulation, Learner) and how they should communicate with each other.

PS: Only use the "anylogic" tab, else you confuse other folks on StackOverflow :)

You need to understand how a model is constructed. If you start an experiment and you see the setup screen, there is no Main and no agents yet.
Once you click "Run", Main is instantiated with the params you give it (or default values).
Once Main exists, it starts instantiating any other agents inside of it.
Try it with a trivial example model: 1 agent inside Main, fed from 1 value set on the experiment. Also, check the help as it explains it in more detail.
PS: The experiment is not an agent itself. It sits "above" any model and has nothing to do with agent-stuff :)

Once again, thank you Benjamin. I understand much better now. Let me try again!
